# Using blocks with dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Trying my hand with blocks in Objective C.
I ran into a strange problem.

Below i have created a block and submitted the block for asynchronous execution on a global dispatch queue.
It doesn't print anything for me. When i replaced the keyword async with sync it works fine and prints the result immediately.

```
@implementation BlockTest
+(void) blocksTest{
__block int m = 0;
void (^__block myblock)(void);
myblock = ^(){
     NSLog(@"myblock %u ", ++m);
};
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"dispatch_async dispatch_get_global_queue");
    myblock();
});
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
[BlockTest blocksTest];
}
```

Can someone please help me with this problem ?

Comment: It's probably because the program ends before async block has a chance to be executed. If you try it in a more real app with AppDelegate, and write your dispatch code in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, you'll see expected result

Comment: You are right Maciej this works perfectly fine in application life cycle. But the issue was about plain objective C project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is exiting before the block has a chance to run.

The nature of an asynchronous call like `dispatch_async()` is that it returns and allows the caller to continue on, possibly before the task that was submitted has completed. Probably before it has even been started.

So, `+blocksTest` returns to the call site in `main()`. `main()` continues to its end (by the way, without returning a value, which is bad for a non-`void` function). When `main()` returns, the whole process exits. Any queues, tasks, worker threads, etc. that GCD was managing is all torn down during process termination.

The process does not wait for all threads to exit or become idle.

You could solve this by calling `dispatch_main()` after the call to `+blocksTest` in `main()`. In that case, though, the program will never terminate unless you submit a task which calls `exit()` at some point. For example, you could put the call to exit inside the block you create in `+blocksTest`.

Actually, in this case, because the task would run on a background thread and not the main thread, anything which delays the immediate exit would be sufficient. For example, a call to `sleep()` for a second would do. You could also run the main run loop for a period of time. There's no period of time that's *guaranteed* to be enough that the global queue has had a chance to run your task to completion, but in practical terms, it would just need a fraction of a second.

There's a complication in that methods to run the run loop exit if there are no input sources or timers scheduled. So, you'd have to schedule a bogus source (like an `NSPort`). As you can tell, this is a kludgy approach if you're not otherwise using the run loop for real stuff.

Comment: Thanks Ken ! This is great. I offloaded my function from ViewController to a plain objective C project but didn't realize there is no event loop running here which ll keep the main thread active.

Comment: This lead me to try dispatch_sync on main queue which doesn't work.

   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"dispatch_sync dispatch_get_main_queue");
        myblock(); }); 
    
I was expecting this to work, do you know whats wrong with it?

Comment: If you use `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)` **from** the main thread, you will always deadlock. `dispatch_sync()` is, of course, synchronous. It doesn't return until the task has run to completion. Until then, the main thread can't do anything else. It's completely blocked. The main queue tries to run its tasks on the main thread. But the main thread is blocked waiting for the task to complete. The task can't run, let alone complete, until the main thread returns to `dispatch_main()` or the main run loop. It's a Catch-22 (unsolvable situation).

Answer (score 0):

Because when you used dispatch_async, the block may have started the execution, but haven't reached the point where you print. However, if you use dispatch_sync, it makes sure that the entire block execution is done before it returns. Remember, dispatch_sync is the main thread.

Comment: `dispatch_sync()` isn't **inherently** the main thread. It's just synchronous. It blocks whatever thread it's called from until the task is completed. The task is *often* run on the thread which called `dispatch_sync()` since that thread is, by definition, not doing anything else. However, it's actually possible that the task is run on some other thread. The docs say "As an optimization, this function invokes the block on the current thread *when possible*." (Emphasis added.)